# Marketing Cloud Connector synchronisation

Tags: marketing-cloud

I received the following message from Salesforce Marketing Cloud Support:

“I would like to inform you that, I would have been glad to help you out with an official document which states that what all is compatible with the SFDC lightning and MC but sadly there is very minimal that i can share. But the official document that we have is, that connector does not support integration between SFDC Lightning and MC. The Sync of the Objects is something that is tested by a few users and have worked for them, but i cannot assure you that as per the standards of the exacttarget it would alwas be working as designed.”

I was wondering whether anyone has knowledge of testing the synchronisation mentioned by Support and whether they have future-proofed their appraoch to finding a fix to the official incompatibility?

I am also interested to know whether anyone with experience in this area would consider the incompatibility as cosmetic or whether they would consider the incompatibility more fundamental in terms of the data sync and process integrity?

Thanks!

Comment: What is the background of this issue that lead to the support case?

Comment: Synchronisation was established via the MC Connector using SFDC Lightning experience and SFMC synchronised data extensions. The issue of incompatibility was raised as this is a known issue. When attempting to identify whether there was a resolution imminent or at least a vision on the roadmap, the following answer from Salesforce Support was provided:

Comment: “I would like to inform you that, I would have been glad to help you out with an official document which states that what all is compatible with the SFDC lightning and MC but sadly there is very minimal that i can share. But the official document that we have is, that connector does not support integration between SFDC Lightning and MC. The Sync of the Objects is something that is tested by a few users and have worked for them, but i cannot assure you that as per the standards of the exacttarget it would alwas be working as designed.”

Comment: The reply raised my questions than answers. Salesforce Support have confirmed a resilution is not on the roadmap. However, they have confirmed too that "a few users and have worked" to create a temporary hack.

Comment: We're keen to know the ramifications of using a tempoary hack. This invariably translates to major problems in the mid-term.

Comment: We're also interested to know whether any Users consider the incompatibility as cosmetic or whether the consensus is this has foundational data integration considerations.